# How do I efficiently overlay two strings where one string takes priority over the other?

Tags: python, range, overlap

I have two strings that act as buffers for ranges of a file. I want to read from this "file" so as to read bytes from the first string in preference to the second string, where there is overlap.

In the examples below, r1 and r2 each represent ranges of the file, which consist of the string along with start and end offsets. I have formatted the examples to make it clearer where in the file the strings exist.

```
def prioritized_read(range1, range2, read_start, read_end):
    # This is the bit I don't know how to write

r1 = ("ABCDEF", (0,6))
r2 = ( "DEF",   (1,4))
assert prioritized_read(r1, r2, 0, 6) == "ABCDEF"

r1 = ("ABC",    (0,3))
r2 = ( "DEF",   (1,4))
assert prioritized_read(r1, r2, 1, 4) == "BCF"

r1 = (  "ABC",  (2,5))
r2 = ("DEF",    (0,3))
assert prioritized_read(r1, r2, 0, 4) == "DEAB"

r1 = ( "A",     (1,2))
r2 = ("DEF",    (0,3))
assert prioritized_read(r1, r2, 0, 3) == "DAF"

r1 = ("ABC",    (0,3))
r2 = (   "DEF", (3,6))
assert prioritized_read(r1, r2, 3, 6) == "DEF"
```

`read_start` and `read_end` will always be bounded by the endpoints of `r1` and `r2`.

The example ranges here are small, but in my application they could be greater than 1 billion, so I'm looking for a solution that is time and memory efficient.

I considered posting this to [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). It seems like it should be an easy and obvious process... but it's defeated me.

N.B. I'm not really reading from a file here, so I can't use solutions involving Python file objects. I'm just using files as a convenient analogy.

Comment: So, what *are* you reading from? Do you have all the data in memory? Are you reading a network stream?  This might influence the nature of the answers.

Comment: All the data will be in memory.

Answer (score 1):

The interval should be divided to subintervals. Let me explain it on this example:

```
r1 = (  "ABC",  (2,5))
r2 = ("DEF",    (0,3))
assert prioritized_read(r1, r2, 0, 4) == "DEAB"
```

Boundaries for subintervals are all the start, end numbers, i.e: `0,2,3,4,5`. Numbers before the read_start and past the read_end can be ignored, so 5 is out. We have now `0,2,3,4`. Less obvious is that `range2` boundaries lying within the `range1` can be ignored as well, so 3 is out too. Boundaries are `0,2,4` which means subintevals are `0-2` and `2-4`.

The rest is easy. We read from that data source which has the required range - respecting the priorities. Ranges do not start from zero, so offsets must be taken in account.

```
def prioritized_read(range1, range2, read_start, read_end):
    d1, r1 = range1
    d2, r2 = range2
    bset = set((read_start, read_end))
    for b in r1: 
        if read_start < b < read_end:
            bset.add(b)
    for b in r2: 
        if not r1[0] < b < r1[1] and read_start < b < read_end:
            bset.add(b)
    boundaries = sorted(bset)

    output = []
    for i in range(len(boundaries) - 1): 
        start, end = boundaries[i], boundaries[i+1]
        if r1[0] <= start < r1[1]:
            # read from #1
            output.append(d1[start-r1[0]:end-r1[0]])
        elif r2[0] <= start < r2[1]: 
            # read from #2
            output.append(d2[start-r2[0]:end-r2[0]])
        else:
            raise ValueError("no data source for {}:{}".format(start, end))
    return "".join(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this gives you the desired output:

```
def prioritized_read(r1, r2, start, end):
    s = [''] * max(r1[1][1], r2[1][1])
    s[r2[1][0]:r2[1][1]] = r2[0]
    s[r1[1][0]:r1[1][1]] = r1[0]

    return ''.join(s[start:end])
```

This assumes that one of the ranges always starts with `0`, and that the ranges are not disjoint. This may not be memory efficient if the ranges are large